# как забиндить работу программы c++

Tags: c++, winapi

Как привязать к кнопке на клавиатуре какое-либо действие? К примеру при нажатии на F3, начать очень быстро кликать и если повторно нажать на F3, программа перестанет быстро кликать?

Делал по этому коду:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
 
void menu()
{
    cout << "Press 'X' to enable and 'Z' to disable autoclicker\n";
}
 
void clicker()
{
    bool click = false; //sets click to false
 
    while (true)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState('X')) //if X is pressed click = true
        {
            click = true; 
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState('Z')) //if 'Z' is pressed click = false
        {
            click = false;
        }
        if (click == true) // if click = true it will press the mouse button down and up really fast
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Sleep(1); //you can adjust the speed of the click here
        }
    }
}       
 
int main()
{
    menu();
    clicker();
 
    return 0;
}
```

Пробовал:

```
void clicker() {
    bool click = false;

while (true) {
    if (GetAsyncKeyState('V')) {
        click = true;
    }
    else if (GetAsyncKeyState('V')) {
        click = false;
    }
    if (click == true) {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Не работает, начинает без остановки кликать, а повторное нажатие V не останавливает работу, так-же пробовал поменять в этих строках V на X

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState('V')) {
            click = true;
```

(Это значит когда кнопка нажата - кликер начинает работу),
И нужно нажать другую, чтобы остановить,
Но это совсем не то, что я задумывал

Comment: @insolor А где вы всё это берёте для правки с очень содержательным сабжем: _в текст добавлено 746 символов_? Вам на почту присылают?

Comment: @0xdb до правки была ссылка на pastebin, я с pastebin перенес в вопрос.

Comment: @insolor А, точно не заметил. Добывляйте хоть в комментарий к правке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного подправил ваш код, вот что получилось:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (GetKeyState('V'))
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Для ваших целей лучше использовать именно `GetKeyState`, т. к. вам нужно сделать включение / выключение по одному нажатию. Подробнее по про [GetKeyState](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate) и про [GetAsyncKeyState](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate).
Add: Так же, если вы пишете кликер для какой-либо игры, то советую поставить вам задержку между кликами, например в 5 миллисекунд, как показано ниже:

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Sleep(5);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Иначе игра попросту может не засчитывать эти клики.